# Highcharts multiple yAxis, the second yAxis labels are not showing but the title is

Tags: highcharts

I have a chart with 2 series and everything is fine except that the 2nd yAxis labels are not showing.

````
              {
                title: {
                  text: 'Humidity'
                },
                labels: {
                  format: '{value} %'
                },
                opposite: false
              },
              {
                title: {
                  text: 'Temperature'
                },
                labels: {
                  format: ' {value} Celcius'
                },
                opposite: true
              },
            ],```
````

Comment: Can you please share your entire code, as the given block looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link the second axis to the first:

```
yAxis: [{
        ...
    },
    {
        ...,
        linkedTo: 0
    }
]
```

---

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/nhgy845k/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.linkedTo

Comment: Do you know why this happens? because sometimes you don't need to link them.

Comment: Hi @Julius Allan Cristobal, You need to link series or another axis to show the labels. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/5yqg8m7s/